# PowerMockito disables Sonar branch coverage

Tags: mockito, code-coverage, sonarqube, powermock

I'm using PowerMockito and @PrepareForTest annotation for my test class. When I do this, Sonar says none of the branches have been covered. However, my other test classes that don't use PowerMockito works well. For example:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({ MyClass.class })
public class MyClassTest {
    //create some mocks and run some tests here
}
```

Is there anyone encountered with the same problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you instrumenting you code for coverage ? Offline instrumentation, online instrumentation ? Probably PowerMockito creates bytecode without coverage collecting instructions. Which coverage tool do you use ?

Comment: I also faced the same issue and as of now I don't have a resolution yet on this. I think this has been there for long time and it needs to be addressed soon.

Answer (score 9):

There is a known issue with PowerMockito and sonar code coverage calculation, and I did a big research on this - as of today, there is no fix to it.
How I personally deal with it - try to avoid the usage of PowerMockito - so use static and final sparsely, which is generally a good advice to have more object oriented code anyway. However, there will still be a few cases were you will need to use static and or final. For these,
compare my answer here:
[cobertura-showing-proper-coverage-but-in-sonar-many-files-showing-0-coverage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28087791/cobertura-showing-proper-coverage-but-in-sonar-many-files-showing-0-coverage)

Answer (score 1):

1. [Add cobertura plugin](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Update+Center) to your sonar server
2. Use the [maven cobertura plugin](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.mojo/cobertura-maven-plugin) in build (I assume that the build uses maven)
3. Feed in cobertura and sonar related properties needed for reporting to your sonar server. example as shown.

   ```
   <sonar.java.coveragePlugin>cobertura</sonar.java.coveragePlugin>
   <sonar.host.url>http://localhost:9500</sonar.host.url>    
   <sonar.sources>${project.build.sourceDirectory}</sonar.sources>
   <sonar.junit.reportsPath>${project.build.directory}/surefire-reports</sonar.junit.reportsPath>
   <sonar.cobertura.reportPath>${project.build.directory}/site/cobertura/coverage.xml</sonar.cobertura.reportPath>
   ```
4. Run maven goal for sonar
   i.e., mvn install sonar:sonar