# Sonar coverage report for PowerMockito

Tags: java, spring-boot, sonarqube

I'm using PowerMockito and @PrepareForTest annotation for my test class. When I do this, Sonar says none of the branches have been covered. However, my other test classes that don't use PowerMockito works well. here is my pom looks like

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.2 </version>
            <scope>test</scope><plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.7.6.201602180812</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-prepare-agent</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-report</id>
                        <!-- <phase>prepare-package</phase> -->
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
        </dependency>
```

Do I need to add anything in this pom ?
Any help is Appreciated, Thanks in Advance

Comment: Powermockito does not work well with Sonar. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27925401/powermockito-disables-sonar-branch-coverage and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28087791/cobertura-showing-proper-coverage-but-in-sonar-many-files-showing-0-coverage

Answer (score 3):

- **PowerMock** doesn't work with sonar in the first step, the cause of the problem is the combination of powermock and jacoco
- We will not face this issue locally, but if we use sonar for test coverage calculations, the error is as follows

```
Could not initialize plugin: interface org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker (alternate: null)
```

- In PowerMock 2.0.9 version, a workaround for this problem is provided they have added an annotation `@PrepareOnlyThisForTest`, this provides the ability for the isolation of a particular Test class.
- Apart from that, we need to add delegate the Runner to SpringRunner using `@PowerMockRunnerDelegate(SpringRunner.class)`

Add Power Mock Dependencies in pom.xml

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito2</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.9</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Use the PowerMock Junit Runner for test Class and declare the test class that we’re mocking and delegate SpringRunner

```
    @RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
    @PrepareOnlyThisForTest(ServiceApplication.class)
    @PowerMockRunnerDelegate(SpringRunner.class)
    public class ExampleControllerTest {
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(ServiceApplication.class);
        Mockito.when(ServiceApplication.getStatic()).thenReturn("");
```

Answer (score 2):

yes right powermock doesn't work with sonar in the first step, the cause of the problem is the combination of powermock and jacoco,
there is already an issue related to this problem (https://github.com/powermock/powermock/issues/727), see here for further informations:

https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/Code-coverage-with-JaCoCo

in the meantime you can try a workaround, as described here:

https://www.geekality.net/2013/09/12/maven-package-runtime-dependencies-in-lib-folder-inside-packaged-jar/

Answer (score 1):

I've found that if you have only one class in the @PrepareForTest annotation e.g.
`@PrepareForTest(ClassA.class)` then jacoco coverage works. It's only when there is more than one class e.g. `@PrepareForTest({ClassA.class, ClassB.class})` that jacoco coverage is reported as 0%

Answer (score -2):

You just need to add the delegate the Runner to SpringRunner;

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PowerMockRunnerDelegate(SpringRunner.class)
```

Comment: Why does anyone think that every Java question relates to Spring? There are a whole world outside of spring and the author didn't mention Spring at all.