# Adding the class for which Junit is written in @PrepareForTest makes a Zero coverage in sonar

Tags: java, junit, sonarqube, jacoco, powermockito

Sample Controller

```
public class SampleController {

    public void sampleMethod() {
    ClassAbc classAbc = new ClassAbc();
    classAbc.abcMethod();
    //doStuff
    }
}
```

ClassAbc

```
public class ClassAbc {
    public void abcMethod() {
    //doStuff
    }
}
```

Junit for SampleController

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PowerMockRunnerDelegate(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({SampleController.class})
public class SampleControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    SampleController sampleController;

    public void setUp() {
        ClassAbc classAbc = PowerMockito.mock(ClassAbc.class);
        PowerMockito.whenNew(ClassAbc.class).withAnyArguments()                                                                                                           
                                          .thenReturn(classAbc);
        doNothing().when(classAbc).abcMethod();
    }

    @Test
    public void testsampleMethod() throws Exception {
        sampleController.sampleMethod();
    }
}
```

When Iam adding the "SampleController.class" in @PrepareForTest ie:

```
@PrepareForTest({SampleController.class})
```

Iam getting the following violation when I run Sonar job.

```
14 more branches need to be covered by unit tests to reach the minimum threshold of 65.0% branch coverage.
```

That is Iam getting zero coverage for that class.

I would like to like if it is necessary to put the class where the constructor is called into the @PrepareForTest annotation instead of the class which is being constructed.

Or can someone find me a solution to fix that Sonar violation.
Thanks in advance

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27925401/powermockito-disables-sonar-branch-coverage

Comment: But It takes more about static and final methods. And hrer I havent got any static methods

Answer (score 1):

As stated in [PowerMockito wiki](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/Code-coverage-with-JaCoCo):

> ... right now there is NO WAY TO USE PowerMock with JaCoCo On-the-fly instrumentation.
>   ... to get code coverage with JaCoCo - use offline Instrumentation ...
>   You may find example of using PowerMock with JaCoCo Offline Instrumentation and Maven in our repository: [jacoco-offline example](https://github.com/powermock/powermock-examples-maven/tree/master/jacoco-offline).